# How to handle tcp server if Client Closes

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have created a programme consisting of a server and client. I have a problem where i dontk know how I can handle the programme crashing when I close the client form while its still connected to the server. I have tried various ways such as `ClientSocket.GetStream().Close();` and `ClientSocket.Close();`. ClientSocket is the name of my TCP client.

How can I send a disconnect request when user presses Disconnect button which sends a Disconnect message to server telling it to drop the client and then closes the client. I Have tried different ways however I am still stuck on trying to get the client to disconnect from the server.

Comment: My C# implementation details are fuzzy, but it's likely that when your client-side socket is `Close`d, any subsequent writes/reads to the stream wrapped around the socket used to communicate with the client will throw an exception. If the client-side socket isn't closed "gracefully" (ie. network disconnect), then you'll probably get the same result but after a timeout.

Comment: @hnefatl within my button listener I close both my tcp connection and the networkstream. However it still throws an exception. A quick question would I also need to close any thread which uses the netstream ?

Comment: Always open and close a connection from the client.  Never from the server.  If the server needs to know when the connection is closing send an application message from client to server that connection is closing.  Then send an application message back from server to client that the message was received.  Then have client close connection.

Comment: @jdweng could you possible give me an example of how to implement this. And would I call the close function before or after sending the message to server.

Comment: You should wait for a response (or at least a period of time).  The TCP messages use timers so you have to be careful not to send a message and immediately close the connection because it is possible the close will occur before the message is received and the server will not see the message.